# React-Native Set Responsive Icon inside Label in Native-Base Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native-base

Hi i need to create form that have password input with masking. So i create the floatinglabel that have label + icon. When the icon clicked it will mask/unmask the password. I had successfully created the label + icon but my problem is the icon is not responsive because there is no button/touchable for the  tag. If i wrap the Icon with Button it gives me the error Nested View within Text. Also i can't use the icon outside the label because it is used for validation icon (X/O)

How to create responsive icon (when user touching) inside Label tags? Or is there any other ways, example like to create more than one icon inside the input.

Here is my code:

```
<Label style={{top: 16}}>
  Password{" "}
  {password_mask && (
    /* If i wrap this icon with button it will gives a error */
    <Icon
      name="ios-eye"
      onPress={() => this.setState({ password_mask: false })}
      style={{top: 16}}
    />
  )}
  {!password_mask && (
    <Icon
      name="ios-eye-off"
      onPress={() => this.setState({ password_mask: true })}
      style={{paddingTop: 5}}
    />
  )}
</Label>
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Try [TouchableOpacity](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity.html). You can render icon inside it. Also you can do some optimizations like this.

```
 <Label style={{ top: 16 }}>
Password{" "}
<TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() =>
        this.setState({ password_mask: !this.state.password_mask })
    }
>
    <Icon
        name={this.state.password_mask ? "ios-eye" : "ios-eye-off"}
        style={this.state.password_mask ? { top: 16 } : { paddingTop: 5 }}
    />
</TouchableOpacity>
</Label>;
```

Comment: Still getting "nesting of View within Text is not supported on Android" error

Comment: I have try change the touchableopacity to touchablenativefeedback but getting error "trying to send command to a non-existing view with tag 88" when the icon is clicked.

Comment: You have to move TouchableOpacity outside your TextInput.

Comment: I don't want my label to be touchable too , i want only the icon is touchable